# How to send a file to Desktop with bash script?

Tags: bash

I am trying to send a file or folder to Desktop with Linux Command Prompt but I don't know how.
Please tell me what command can I use for this?

Comment: what means "send" to you ? move a file/folder ? copy it ?

Comment: `mv /path/to/the/file ~/Desktop`

Comment: Yes, I can use this but I don't want to move file, I want to create a shortcut to Desktop!

Comment: `ln -s /path/to/the/file ~/Desktop/file`

Answer (score 1):

The move command mv. Use man mv for more information, as this command is a lot more complex than it seems. With cd Desktop/ you should be able to find your desktop on variations of linux like Mint or Ubuntu. To find your present working directory, as in your current path for the terminal, type pwd. This will give you your directory which will be similar to /home/Desktop.